# How to implement ConsumerSeekAware in Spring-kafka?

Tags: spring, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am trying to implement a consumer with @KafkaListener.
I am using Spring `2.3.7` version.

Here is my code so far,

```
public class SampleListener {

@KafkaListener(topics = "test-topic",
        containerFactory = "sampleKafkaListenerContainerFactory",
        groupId = "test-group")
public void onMessage(@Payload String message,
                              @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
                              @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                              @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) long receivedTimestamp,
                              @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) long offset,
                              @Headers MessageHeaders messageHeaders) {

    LOGGER.info("Received Message for topic={} partition={} offset={} messageHeaders={}",
            topic, partition, offset, messageHeaders);
    LOGGER.debug("Received Message payload={}", message);
    doSomething(message);

   }
}
```

I am new to Kafka and Spring. I read the spring-kafka docs on how to seek offsets but not able to understand completely.

My understanding, for my use case I don't want to read the events again when partitions are assigned to a container or in any other scenarios (Ensuring read only once).

I see most Consumer implementations implements `ConsumerSeekAware`. I know implementing `ConsumerSeekAware` gives us the ability to seek offset on events like `onIdleContainer` or `onPartitionsAssigned`. I am not able to understand what are the scenarios being handled with these?

1. What are the scenarios `ConsumerSeekAware` is implemented to handle? What are the best practices or general scenarios in implementing Kafka Consumer which require seeking offset?
2. What is the difference between `registerSeekCallback` and `onPartitionsAssigned` ? For both it says they are called whenever partitions are assigned. What is the difference between callBack for both these methods?

Answer (score 5):

1. 

Implementing `ConsumerSeekAware` allows you to

a. Seek to a specific offset (or beginning, end, or an offset represented by a timestamp during initialization.

b. Peform seeks at any time during the lifecycle of the application.

The preferred technique is to extend `AbstractConsumerSeekAware` if possible because it takes care of much of the underlying complexity.

If you don't need to seek, then you don't need to implement the interface (or extend the abstract class).

> My understanding, for my use case I don't want to read the events again when partitions are assigned to a container or in any other scenarios (Ensuring read only once).

The container will automatically commit the offsets for you (by default when all the records returned by a `poll()`, but you can set the container `AckMode` property to `RECORD` to commit the offset after each record is processed).

The next time you start the application, it will start consuming from the last committed offset(s).

2.

`onPartitionsAssigned` is called when partitions are assigned (initially or after a rebalance). If you perform seeks there, they invoke the consumer directly, during the rebalance.

`registerSeekCallback` is called to give the application a handle to a callback that can be invoked at any arbitrary time in the future. If the container has concurrency > 1 then multiple callbacks are registered. When you perform seeks on these callbacks, they are queued for the consumer thread to invoke just before the next poll. (The consumer is not thread-safe). The abstract class manages this for you and allows a higher level of abstraction...

```java
/**
* Rewind all partitions one record.
*/
public void rewindAllOneRecord() {
    getSeekCallbacks()
        .forEach((tp, callback) ->
            callback.seekRelative(tp.topic(), tp.partition(), -1, true));
}

/**
* Rewind one partition one record.
*/
public void rewindOnePartitionOneRecord(String topic, int partition) {
    getSeekCallbackFor(new org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition(topic, partition))
        .seekRelative(topic, partition, -1, true);
}
```

In the upcoming 2.6.0 release (due this week), it's even easier, with methods `seekToBeginning()`, `seekToEnd()` and `seekToTimeStamp()` which will queue seeks for all assigned partitions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
1. I know this can be specific to the application requirements but my 1st question was to understand the best practices or general scenarios to seek offset while implementing Kafka consumer
2. Any specific reason why `AbstractConsumerSeekAware` doesn't implement `onIdleContainer`?

Comment: What would you expect the abtract class to do in `onIdleContainer`? That is normally application-specific; it doesn't need to implement it because it has a default implementation in the interface. It only implements the methods it needs to perform the exposed support functions.

Comment: @GaryRussell thanks for answer, I have a related question. What if I have some extra logic in `onPartitionsAssigned` that can fail and in such case I want to let kafka broker know that app is not successful with partitions assignment and broker should try to assign it to another client in the same group? How do I behave in this funciton then, don't call the callback?

Comment: `onPartitionsAssigned` is a passive method to tell you what happened, it is not a request "do you want these partitions"; there is no communication back to the broker. You would have to stop the listener container to force a rebalance.

Comment: tx so much, only saw it now (notification missed me). follow up question: with `ConsumerSeekAware` is it guaranteed that `onPartitionsAssigned`, messages sent to method annotated with `@KafkaListener` and `onPartitionsRevoked` are happening in this order? in other words, is it guaranteed that messages won't be sent before `onPartitionsAssigned` and that `onPartitionsRevoked` won't be called before the assign?

Comment: Yes; however, older versions of kafka-clients used to call `onPartitionsRevoked` with an empty list before `onPartitionsAssigned`. I don't remember when that changed.

Comment: I think I'm still seeing empty list of partitions in `onPartitionsRevoked` in 2.6.7, so it could have been after that. Thanks!

Comment: @GaryRussell one more question about the ConsumerSeekAware; I know you've already told about the order of calls: 1. `onPartitionsRevoked`, 2. `onPartitionsAssigned`. However, will broker wait for the `onPartitionsRevoked` call to return before calling `onPartitionsAssigned`? Bonus question is, will it wait for all `onPartitionsRevoked` within a consumer group to return before starting the assignment within this group?

Comment: ^^ checked it myself by adding `sleep` in `onPartitionsRevoked`, answers to questions are: yes and yes

Comment: Generally, yes, but if cooperative assignment is used, the algorithm is different, because only a subset of the partitions are revoked and you can continue to consume from the partitions that are still assigned; assignment is completed later.