# Spring Kafka Consumer seek particular offset to read message

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I created a SpringBootApplication to consume a message from Particular offset. But consumer poll method returning zero records. If I run application multiple times it should return same message each time from 108134L offset.

```java
@Configuration
public class FlightEventListener {

    @Bean
    public void listenForMessage() throws Exception {
        
        TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition("topic-name", 0);
        KafkaConsumer<String, Object> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(clusterOneProps);
        
        try {
            consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("topic-name"), new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                consumer.seek(tp, 108134L); 
            }
        });
            
        ConsumerRecords<String, Object> crs = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100L));
        System.out.println(crs.count());
         for (ConsumerRecord<String, Object> record : crs) {
                   System.out.println("consumer Record is >>>>"+record.offset());
                   System.out.println("consumer Record is >>>>"+record);
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
```

================================================

Implemented ConsumerSeekAware. but  method is not invoking. How to invoke the method.    I am looking for method invocation during startup

```java
 @Configuration
public class MessageSeeker extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware {

        
     @Autowired
        private FlightEventKafkaConfiguration clusterOneConfig;
     
     @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
   // logic

}
```

Comment: You need to implement `ConsumerSeekAware`, does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63663661/how-to-implement-consumerseekaware-in-spring-kafka

Comment: Implemented ConsumerSeekAware. but  method is not invoking. How to invoke the method. edited Question

Comment: Not sure why you tagged this with spring-kafka; you are not using it - you are creating a `KafkaConsumer` yourself. `ConsumerSeekAware` only applies when you are using the framework. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek You need to wait for assignment (or use `assign()` instead of `subscribe()`.) The first poll, generally, will not return any records.